# How to return data from subscriber next method in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

My project in angular consist of lot calls to api, in which most of the code accomplish the common task like saving the response to a variable. I need to optimize the code for performance. So I thought of doing something like below.

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilsService {

  constructor( private _api: ApirequestService ) { }

  getItems(url, data, succFunc?: (data) => void, errFunc?: (err) => void, compFunc?: () => void) {
    return this._api.fetchApiData(url,data).subscribe(
      data => {
        if( succFunc != undefined && typeof succFunc == 'function' ) succFunc(data);
      },
      error => {
        if( errFunc != undefined && typeof errFunc == 'function' ) errFunc(error);
      },
      () => {
        if( compFunc != undefined && typeof compFunc == 'function' ) compFunc();
      }
    )
  }
```

I created a service and injected logic outside as a parameter of the function. Is there better way to accomplish the same task with better logic. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi, just to understand why not just subscribe outside of your UtilsService ?

Comment: just to eliminate the code repetition.

Comment: On your sample, code repetition is minimal, is just to not directly call `this._api.fetchApiData(url,data)` out of `UtilsService` ?